# How to select the content between two specific elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two constant element: (always there are exist)

- `span.start`
- `span.stop`

Here is my HTML structure *(pattern)*:

`...` = `/* each tag|string|element can be in here */`

```
...

<span class="start"> ... </span>

...   /* now I want to select every-text is in here */

<span class="stop"> /... </span>

...
```

**Note:** I want to select just text contents (`.text()`)

---

Here is an **example**:

```
<div class="one">
    <a href="www.example.com">LinkName</a>
    there is sometimes a string
    <span class="start">what</span>              // --------------- beginning of range
    I
    <div>want</div>                              
    <span>to</span>
    <span class="stop">select</span>             // --------------- end of range
    <div class="two">
        there can be any element/string else
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I want this **output:**

> `what I want to select`

---

What I tried::

```
var content = $('body').html().split($('span.stop')[0].outerHTML)[0].trim().text();
```

But this ^ is just depends on `span.stop`. In other word, it just selects all text on the top *(before, behind)* `span.stop`.

Comment: Are the 2 spans always siblings?

Comment: @cmbuckley *(good question)*, Yes they are.

Comment: Is there always something after `.stop` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Not *always*. But it can be one or two elements after `span.stop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the pseudo-code:

get the parent elements child nodes:
from the node that equals "start" node:
get the text content from each next node until "end" node is reached

```js
function getTextInbetween(startNode, stopNode) {
    if (startNode.parentElement != stopNode.parentElement) return;

    var elements = startNode.parentElement.childNodes;

    // Get Start-Position
    var startPos = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        if (elements[i] == startNode) {
            startPos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    //var startPos = [].indexOf.call(elements, startNode); // Short version of the loop

    // Get all the text from start to stop
    var text = "";
    for (var i = startPos; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        text += elements[i].textContent;
        if (elements[i] == stopNode) {
            break;
        }
    }
  
    // remove lines and spaces as HTML does
    text = text.trim();
    text = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");

    return text;
}

var startNode = document.getElementsByClassName("start")[0];
var stopNode = document.getElementsByClassName("stop")[0];
var text = getTextInbetween(startNode, stopNode);
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <a href="www.example.com">LinkName</a>
  there is sometimes a string
  <span class="start">what</span>
  I
  <div>want</div>
  <span>to</span>
  <span class="stop">select</span>
  <div class="two">
    there can be any element/string else
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shafizadeh haha for some reason it was not in the HTML - the code works :)

Comment: Note that you cold shorten the function with some funky array methods. But I think like this it is the best to understand.

Comment: The loop for the start position seems unnecessary, it might be nicer to use `var startPos = [].indexOf.call(elements,startNode);`

Comment: @CodeiSir Yes, I think what you have wore is more readable ..!

Comment: @SmokeyPHP yes.. I thought about that, but it might be slower as well. I'll add this as a comment, so the user can decide what he preferse  thanks

Comment: @CodeiSir _"I don't think there is a proper solution with jQuery only."_ See post

Comment: @guest271314 yeah that sentence is stupid I'll remove it. What it was meant to say no super easy solution like the example in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.contents()` , `.map()` , `.prevAll()` , `.is()` , `$.trim()` , `.get()` , `Array.prototype.filter()`

```js
var text = $(".one").contents().map(function(i, el) {
  if ($(el).prevAll(".start").is("*") && !$(el).is(".stop, .stop ~ *"))
    return $.trim(el.textContent || el)
  else return null
}).get().filter(Boolean);

console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <a href="www.example.com">LinkName</a>
  there is sometimes a string
  <span class="start">what</span> // --------------- beginning of range I
  <div>want</div>
  <span>to</span>
  <span class="stop">select</span> // --------------- end of range
  <div class="two">
    there can be any element/string else
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Including both `.start` , `.stop` elements text

```js
var text = $(".one").contents().map(function(i, el) {
  if (($(el).is(".start, .start + *, .start ~ *:not(.stop + *)") 
       || $(el).prev(".start").is("*"))
      && !$(el).is(".stop ~ *") && el.nodeType !== 8)
    return $.trim(el.textContent || el)
  else return null
}).get().filter(Boolean);

console.log(text, text.join(" "))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <a href="www.example.com">LinkName</a> there is sometimes a string
  <span class="start">what</span>
  <!--------------- beginning of range -->
  I
  <div>want</div>
  <span>to</span>
  <span class="stop">select</span> NOT THIS
  <!--------------- end of range -->
  <div class="two">
    there can be any element/string else
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get `[object Array]["// --------...", "want", "to", "// --------..."]` :S

Comment: Note: you should remove the comments, and don't forget the "I" in that line 

Comment: @CodeiSir _"I get [object Array]["// --------...", "want", "to", "// --------..."] :S"_ Interesting. Returns `["// --------------- beginning of range I", "want", "to", "// --------------- end of range"]` at stacksnippets , here . Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: That was copy past from the console, the strings are actually longer. But you should to `Array.join(" ")`

Comment: @CodeiSir _"Note: you should remove the comments, and don't forget the "I" in that line ; ) "_ Those are are not valid `html` comments, but text of element. Yes, `"I"` is included in text

Comment: The purpose of the "comments" are only for the question, so you should not really use it in the example^^ And the "I" was in the next line

Comment: @CodeiSir _"The purpose of the "comments" are only for the question, so you should not really use it^^ And the "I" was in the next line "_ Yes, returns same results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97144/discussion-between-codeisir-and-guest271314).

Comment: Nice jQuery! Just note that this might not be very performant.

Comment: Sorry, found another issue.. it will keep all whitespaces and new lines if there are some

Comment: @CodeiSir _"Sorry, found another issue.. it will keep all whitespaces and new lines if there are some "_ Included `$.trim()` , `.filter(Boolean)` to address part of this, though did consider newlines. Was not certain if text should even be trimmed , or if entire content was expected . Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: He obviously wants it to be the same text as displayed, no junk from source code. Sorry I can't do Fiddle now, I'm not on my pc

Comment: @CodeiSir _"He obviously wants it to be the same text as displayed, no junk from source code. Sorry I can't do Fiddle now, I'm not on my pc"_ Try not to presume what is "obvious" here; could be incorrect presumption. `$.trim()` call should address some of space character issue.  How did determine _"it will keep all whitespaces and new lines if there are some"_ if did not check ?

Comment: I tested it. But the fiddle is not saving here, so I can't post

Comment: @CodeiSir http://jsfiddle.net/uk1hr1Ld/4 contains newline character before and after "I" , which are not returned to resulting array or string ; why included `$.trim()` and else return null within `.map()` and `.filter(Boolean)` chained to `.map()` . Is this saved jsfiddled tested http://jsfiddle.net/uk1hr1Ld/7/ ? Could include `.replace()` following `$.trim()` to address space characters http://jsfiddle.net/uk1hr1Ld/9/ . Though note, this is not case described at OP ?

Answer (score -1):

Try using jquery next() selector to access siblings till you reach the stop node.
You can read more about it here along with example
https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: `.next()` will ignore pure text nodes / text that is not in a tag. So in this case the `I` would be missed